# OpenCV:Ubuntu:NetBeans:cvSubdiv2DEdgeOrg "undeclared"

Tags: opencv, netbeans-6.9, ubuntu-11.10

I am using OpenCV 2.4 with NetBeans 7.0.1 on Ubuntu 11.10.

When I try to compile code that contains the following

```
CvSubdiv2DPoint* pt = cvSubdiv2DEdgeOrg( t );
```

I get the following compilation error

```
error: there are no arguments to ‘cvSubdiv2DEdgeOrg’ that depend on a template parameter, so a declaration of ‘cvSubdiv2DEdgeOrg’ must be available [-fpermissive]
note: (if you use ‘-fpermissive’, G++ will accept your code, but allowing the use of an undeclared name is deprecated)
```

When I right click on CvSubdiv2DPoint and choose Navigate:Got to Declaration/Definition, it is defined in types_c.h.  I do not understand how I get get to the definition if it is allegedly "undeclared".  Also, if I include

```
#include "types_c.h"
```

and make sure that types_c.h is in the include path, I still get the error message above.

Any assistance in resolving this problem would be greatly appreciated,
Peter.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It was moved to legacy. You need to include its header:

```
#include "opencv2/legacy/legacy.hpp"
```